# Search and replace text file content using VBA Regex

Tags: regex, vba, text-files

I'm using the code below (Thanks Maco for that) to replace text in multiple text files without opening and replacing manually.

It works, but I want to be able to replace content containing an error, like:

> exem
> -tion

I want to remove the enter mark at the end of the line and the dash so that the text becomes

> exemtion

A simple macro in Notepad++ can do it easily but then you have to open each file manually, not so efficient for hundreds of files.

Can this be modified with Regex in it?

```vb
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

    Dim objFSO As Object, objFil As Object, objFil2 As Object
    Dim StrFileName As String, StrFolder As String, strAll As String, newFileText As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    StrFolder = "c:\macro\"
    StrFileName = Dir(StrFolder & "*.txt")

    Do While StrFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objFil = objFSO.opentextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        strAll = objFil.readall
        objFil.Close
        Set objFil2 = objFSO.createtextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        'change this to that in text
        newFileText = Replace(strAll, "THIS", "THAT")
        'change from to to in text
        newFileText = Replace(newFileText, "from", "to")
        'write file with new text
        objFil2.Write newFileText
        objFil2.Close
        StrFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to remove a specified pattern

```vb
Public Function removePattern(searchPattern As String, strText As String) As String

Dim regEx As Object
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regEx
    .Pattern = searchPattern
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    
    removePattern = .Replace(strText, vbNullString)
    
End With

End Function
```

Then add this line of code to your sub:

```
newFileText = removePattern("([\r\n" & Chr(11) & "]-)", strAll)
```

This pattern looks for all kinds of line breaks followed by a hypen.
`Chr(11)` looks for the soft return - there is no equivalent regex-placeholder. Therefore it has to be put there as string.